# Scrapy Not Returning Additonal Info from Scraped Link in Item via Request Callback

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Basically the code below scrapes the first 5 items of a table. One of the fields is another href and clicking on that href provides more info which I want to collect and add to the original item. So `parse` is supposed to pass the semi populated item to `parse_next_page` which then scrapes the next bit and should return the completed `item` back to `parse`

Running the code below only returns the info collected in `parse`
If I change the `return items` to `return request` I get a completed item with all 3 "things" but I only get 1 of the rows, not all 5.
Im sure its something simple, I just can't see it.

```
class ThingSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "thing"
allowed_domains = ["somepage.com"]
start_urls = [
"http://www.somepage.com"
]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    items = []

    for x in range (1,6):
        item = ScrapyItem()
        str_selector = '//tr[@name="row{0}"]'.format(x)
        item['thing1'] = hxs.select(str_selector")]/a/text()').extract()
        item['thing2'] = hxs.select(str_selector")]/a/@href').extract()
        print 'hello'
        request = Request("www.nextpage.com", callback=self.parse_next_page,meta={'item':item})
        print 'hello2'
        request.meta['item'] = item
        items.append(item)      

    return items


def parse_next_page(self, response):
    print 'stuff'
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['thing3'] = hxs.select('//div/ul/li[1]/span[2]/text()').extract()
    return item
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [pyOpenSSL](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL) , sometimes fiddler also creates problem for "https:\*" requests. Close fiddler if running and run spider again. Another problem which is in your code that you are using a generator in parse method and not using 'yeild' to return the request to scrapy scheduler. You should do it like this....

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    items = []

for x in range (1,6):
    item = ScrapyItem()
    str_selector = '//tr[@name="row{0}"]'.format(x)
    item['thing1'] = hxs.select(str_selector")]/a/text()').extract()
    item['thing2'] = hxs.select(str_selector")]/a/@href').extract()
    print 'hello'
    request = Request("www.nextpage.com",callback=self.parse_next_page,meta{'item':item})
    if request:
         yield request
    else:
         yield item
```

Comment: Hi Ifzall, im not really clear on your answer. Could you explain the if statement a bit more?

Comment: Ive tried putting your code into my spider and it does not work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the SSL and Fiddler things.. they were not meant for you. I mixed two answers here.. :p
Now come to your code, you said

> Running the code below only returns the info collected in parse

that's right because you are returning a list of 5 items populated with the 'thing1' and 'thing2' returning item here will not cause scrapy engine to send the request to the call back 'parse_next_page' as shown below.

```
for x in range (1,6):
    item = ScrapyItem()
    str_selector = '//tr[@name="row{0}"]'.format(x)
    item['thing1'] = hxs.select(str_selector")]/a/text()').extract()
    item['thing2'] = hxs.select(str_selector")]/a/@href').extract()
    print 'hello'
    request = Request("www.nextpage.com", callback=self.parse_next_page,meta={'item':item})
    print 'hello2'
    request.meta['item'] = item
    items.append(item)      

return items
```

then you said...

> ```
> If I change the return items to return request I get a completed item with all 3 "things" but I only get 1 of the rows, not all 5.
> ```

that's also true because you are using 'return request' outside the loop which executes only last request created in loop and not the first 4. So either make a 'list of requests' and return in outside the loop or use 'yield request' inside the loop.. this should work definitely as I have tested same case myself. Returning items inside the parse will not retrieve the 'thing3'.

simply apply any one solution and your spider should run like missile....

Comment: I have deleted return items and put yield request directly under items.append(item) inside the loop as you have suggested and touched nothing else...but I only get the 1 result still?!?!?

Comment: I have tried the other way too by having items.append(request) and then return items outside the loop. Still only 1 result. :(

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. yarr.. change the code into this..

```
def parse(self, response):
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
items = []

for x in range (1,6):
    item = ScrapyItem()
    str_selector = '//tr[@name="row{0}"]'.format(x)
    item['thing1'] = hxs.select(str_selector")]/a/text()').extract()
    item['thing2'] = hxs.select(str_selector")]/a/@href').extract()
    print 'hello'
    request = Request("www.nextpage.com", callback=self.parse_next_page,meta={'item':item})
    print 'hello2'
    yield request
    #donot return or yield item here.. only yield request return item in the callback.


def parse_next_page(self, response):
    print 'stuff'
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['thing3'] = hxs.select('//div/ul/li[1]/span[2]/text()').extract()
    return item
```

I think now its pretty clear...

Comment: I still only get 1 result not 5. The loop goes around 5 times as I see 5 'hello's but I only see 'stuff' once and the spider only returns one set of results.