# Scrapy Not Returning After Yielding a Request

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Similar to the person here: [Scrapy Not Returning Additonal Info from Scraped Link in Item via Request Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276663/scrapy-not-returning-additonal-info-from-scraped-link-in-item-via-request-callba), I am having difficulty accessing the list of items I build in my callback function. I have tried building the list both in the parse function (but doesn't work because the callback hasn't returned), and the callback, but neither have worked for me.

I am trying to return all the items that I build from these requests. Where do I call "return items" such that the item has been fully processed? I am trying to replicate the tutorial (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#using-our-item)
Thanks!!

The relevant code is below:

```
class ASpider(Spider):
    items = []
...
  def parse(self, response):
      input_file = csv.DictReader(open("AFile.txt"))
      x = 0
      for row in input_file:
          yield  Request("ARequest", 
          cookies = {"arg1":"1", "arg2":row["arg2"], "style":"default", "arg3":row["arg3"]}, callback = self.aftersubmit, dont_filter = True)

  def aftersubmit(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    # Create new object..
    item = AnItem()
    item['Name'] = "jsc"
    return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` (or `yield`) an item from the `aftersubmit`callback method. Quote from [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spiders):

> In the callback function, you parse the response (web page) and return
>   either Item objects, Request objects, or an iterable of both.

```
def aftersubmit(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)

    item = AnItem()
    item['Name'] = "jsc"
    return item
```

Note that this particular `Item` instance doesn't make sense since you haven't really put anything from the response into it's fields.

Comment: I actually had that in my code, but still was not able to add the returned item to the list, as shown above

Comment: @jsc123 ok, but what do you need the list of items for exactly?

Comment: So that I can add all the items to a CSV. Similar to the tutorial (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#using-our-item), I want to be able to return the CSV by using this command: scrapy crawl ASpider -o items.csv -t csv

Comment: @jsc123 exactly, this is a job for scrapy [`Item Exporters`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html). You need this one: [`CsvItemExporter`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.contrib.exporter.CsvItemExporter).

Comment: @jsc123 the job of a spider is to extract the data, put it inside the item instances and return. Exporting is done by the item exporter later. Think about it as a "chain of responsibility".

Comment: Could we move this to chat / would you mind giving an example of how to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54468/discussion-between-jsc123-and-alecxe).