# simple scrapy based on https://github.com/scrapy/quotesbot/blob/master/quotesbot/spiders/toscrape-xpath.py not passing data using yield Request

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, meta

**strong text**My code based on examples that I searched did not seem to function as intended so I decided to use a working model found on github: https://github.com/scrapy/quotesbot/blob/master/quotesbot/spiders/toscrape-xpath.py
I then modified it slightly to showcase what I am running into. The code below works great as intended but my ultimate goal is to pass the scraped data from first "parse"  to a second "parse2" function so that I can combine data from 2 different pages. But for now I wanted to start very simple so I can follow what is happening, hence the heavily stripped code below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from quotesbot.items import MyItems
from scrapy import Request


class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'toscrape-xpath'
    start_urls = [
    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    item = MyItems()
    for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
            item['tinfo'] = 
quote.xpath('./span[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
            yield item 



but then when I modify the code as below:

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from quotesbot.items import MyItems
from scrapy import Request


class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'toscrape-xpath'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    item = MyItems()
    for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
            item['tinfo'] =  
            quote.xpath('./span[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
            yield Request("http://quotes.toscrape.com/", 
    callback=self.parse2, meta={'item':item})

def parse2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    yield item
```

I only have one item scraped and it says the rest are duplicates. It also looks like "parse2" is not even read at all. I have played with the indentation and the brackets thinking I am missing something simple, but without much success. I have looked at many examples to see if I can make sense of what could be the issue but I still am not able to make it work. I am sure its a very simple issue for those gurus out there, so I yelp "Help!" somebody!

also my items.py file looks like below and I think those two files items.py and toscrape-xpath.py are the only ones in action as far as I can tell since I am quite new to all this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`enter code here`

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class QuotesbotItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    pass

class MyItems(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    tinfo = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Thank you very much to any and all help you can provide

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from quotesbot.items import MyItems
from scrapy import Request


class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'toscrape-xpath'
    start_urls = [
    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    item = MyItems()
    for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
            item = 
{'tinfo':quote.xpath('./span[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()}
    **yield response.follow**('http://quotes.toscrape.com', self.parse_2, 
meta={'item':item})

def parse_2(self, response):
    print "almost there"
    item = response.meta['item']
    yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

Your spider logic is very confusing:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
            yield Request("http://quotes.toscrape.com/", 
    callback=self.parse2, meta={'item':item})
```

For every quote you find on `quotes.toscrape.com` you schedule another request with to the same webpage? 
What happens is that these new scheduled requests get filtered out by scrapys duplicate request filter.

Maybe you should just yield the item right there:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
        item = MyItems()
        item['tinfo'] = quote.xpath('./span[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

To illustrate why your current crawler does nothing see this drawing:
[image]

Comment: @jayuya could you elaborate more what you want to do? 1st request goes to quotes.toscrape.com; where would the 2nd request go? It cannot go to quotes.toscrape.com again, well at least it doesn't make sense for it to do so.

Comment: Ok my friend, let me reword it a bit differently, why is the code not "yielding" in the parse2 function? I need it to yield the item in the parse2 function so I can learn about meta or to pass data from one parse function into another in a very simple example.

Comment: Thank you Granitosaurus for your help, I think I need to explain a bit more for what I am trying to do here:  the first part of my code is actually the same to yours, the copy/paste I did kind of combined 2 pieaces of code together The ultimate goal is to do like https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=Passing%20additional%20data%20to%20callback%20functions where they show how to "Passing additional data to callback functions". All I am doing is just take a working example and modify it so I can learn how to pass data using meta, which seems to not work for me

Comment: @jayuya You're still not understanding the problem here. See my edit of the answer. Your crawler simply does not make sense - the Request you yield in `parse` has to go somewhere else than the same url.

Comment: excellent illustration, now, let me ask this:  how do I obtain the same results as in your code but instead  using pseudo code like mine that has a second parse function and meta? I saw similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276663/scrapy-not-returning-additonal-info-from-scraped-link-in-item-via-request-callba, another example is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578918/scrapy-unable-to-make-request-callback#15580501, but I don't quite follow the solution

Comment: @jayuya if you want to chain requests (i.e. go to url1 -> make item -> go to url2 -> append to previously made item) you need every of your items to have individual url. If you look at the illustration then the bottom square should read something like `got to quotes.toscrape.com/quote/<quote_id>`, but this particular page is flat and individual quotes don't have their own pages, so if you want to explore request chaining you should find a new site that has products and invidual product pages.

Comment: I found another example that uses "yield response.follow" and that seems to work closer to what I am looking for. How can I make the last piece of code loop more than one time? It should loop something like 8 times but it only loops 1 time at the moment. The results should be the same as results obtained from Granitosaurus's code. Is that even possible to loop more than 1 time with this code?..thank you again.